# Bootstrap row over leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I'm trying to put over a leaflet map a bootstrap row, my html is:

```
<div class="row-fluid some" id="map">
    <div class="span1"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
</div>
```

span1 and span2 are columns with some information with rgba background. the leftover columns are a visible map area.

The problem is the map is showing over the columns and they are visible only when map is loading or zooming out.

span1 and span2 have `z-index: 2000`

How to I can put columns visible over the map?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put them in a common container, and absolutely position the row you want to overlay the map.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vwQPE/6/) (with Leaflet)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="mapbox">
        <div class="row-fluid some" id="map">
            <img src="//placehold.it/600x400">
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid overlay">
            <div class="span1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <button class="btn">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.mapbox {
    position: relative;
}

.mapbox .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 314159;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.mapbox .overlay .btn {
    pointer-events: initial;
}
```

Clicking through an element is possible by specifying `pointer-events: none`.  Note that this by default removes the ability to click children of said element (because the default `pointer-events` value is `inherit`), so declare `pointer-events: initial` on those elements you want to be able to interact with.

<sub>note: the reason the buttons are stacking on the fiddle is Bootstrap's media queries, are seeing the small preview as a mobile-phone size.</sub>

Comment: it works, but it has a big problem: we can't interact with the map.

Comment: [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/vwQPE/2/) if you try to interact inside second row-fluid it doesn't works. But we can drag the map outside `.overlay`

Comment: @papelucho, I added a z-index and a click handler to the blue button.  It works for me.

Comment: You are right. But my problem is: is not possible drag the map in the gray area, [look](http://jsfiddle.net/vwQPE/5/). So, how to use a bootstrap row and interact with the map in area without columns?

Comment: @papelucho, `pointer-events` will fix that. I updated the answer and fiddle.

Comment: Works fine. Just need to change `pointer-events: initial` to `pointer-events: auto`.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm testing over FF, but apparently pointer-events is not supported by IE and Opera.